# if multiple users run a query that creates a temp table at the same time, would the data in the table be corrupted in each session?

Tags: postgresql, query, plpgsql, postgresql-12

I am using postgres12. I have a query that creates a temp table named table_x and returns it. I am wondering if this data will be corrupted since there is multiple users running the same query at the same time, and will all be creating a table with the same name? Would they be editing each others temp table? How does postgres behave in these circumstances?

**BTW**:
The data returned in each temp table is unique to the user making the query.

Also, I have attempted to structure the query like so:

```
return table (

)

return query;
```

However, I need the results from multiple return queries to be returned in the table, meaning I would need it to look like:

```
return table (
)

return query;

return query;

return query;
```

And I have not found success with this structure so far.

If anyone has advice, it will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a temporary table in PostgreSQL, only the connection that created that temp table will be able to access it because it is generated in a unique schema for that connection. This is to avoid the very conflicts you're asking about (by using schema separation). This [StackOverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33657970/5059085) provides more details regarding this.

You can also read more on the documentation for [CREATE TABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-createtable.html).